# Hibernate Custom ID generator Exception while deploying to weblogic

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, weblogic

I am recently working on a task where I am refactoring an old  web project. First I tried to run the project on my local weblogic instance before starting refactoring.

While I try to deploy the application I got a hibernate exception as follows ==>

```
Caused By: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown Id.generator: unique-id
at org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper.makeIdGenerator(BinderHelper.java:428)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindId(AnnotationBinder.java:1901)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1279)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:754)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.processArtifactsOfType(AnnotationConfiguration.java:546)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

The exception above implying that it couldn't find the id generator named "unique-id" .  Then I dig in to the code and see that the id field in the entity is string. and  there is a custom ID generator class that is implementing hibernate IdentifierGenerator class where it is calling a db function for generating alphanumeric id for each time it is called. Below is piece of code in the entity class where it defines the type of id generation.

```
  @Id
  @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, length = 18)
  @GenericGenerator(name = "unique-id", strategy = "com.common.entity.RowIdGenerator")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "unique-id")
  private String id;
```

And here is the RowIdGenerator class for generating alphanumeric id.

```
 public class RowIdGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator
{
  private final static String SQL_TEXT = "SELECT TCC.F_ROW_ID_GEN FROM DUAL";

  @Override
  public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor sessionImplemetor, Object object) throws HibernateException
  {
    return this.getNextNumber(sessionImplemetor);
  }

  private String getNextNumber(SessionImplementor session)
  {
    try
    {
      ResultSet rs = null;
      PreparedStatement statement = null;
      try
      {
        statement = session.getBatcher().prepareSelectStatement(SQL_TEXT);
        rs = statement.executeQuery();
        String nextValue = null;
        if (rs.next())
          nextValue = rs.getString(1);
        if (nextValue == null)
          throw new HibernateException("is is null.");
        return nextValue;
      } 
      finally
      {
        if (rs != null)
          rs.close();
        if (statement != null)
          session.getBatcher().closeStatement(statement);
      }
    } catch (SQLException sqle)
    {
      throw JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(session.getFactory().getSQLExceptionConverter(), sqle, "could not fetch initial value for increment generator", SQL_TEXT);
    }
  }

}
```

What may cause this error? I see that the generator named "unique-id" is defined and annotated. As far as I know there is no error in the code, maybe it is because of the configuration of my local weblogic instance but Any comment and advice would be appreciated.

regards

Answer (score 0):

You can auto generate only number as ids.Auto generation for other types like String is not supported by hibernate

Comment: Actually it is not autogenerating. as I mentioned, it is using a custom class where it is calling a db function for generating an alphanumeric unique id each time it is called.

Comment: It seems you are not passing parameters in your GenericGenerator. Could you try passing the parameters and check again

Comment: As it is not configuring something in custom class I think it doesnt need parameters.

Comment: Try removing strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY

Comment: The problem is solved by adding the entity definitions to persistence.xml.